# UnsupportedOperationException when access webhdfs

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hue, webhdfs

Im getting this error when access

```
http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1

{
"RemoteException": 
"exception":"UnsupportedOperationException",
"javaClassName":"java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException",
"message":"op=NULL is not supported"
}
```

I have set webhdfs true in hdfs-site.xml
how to fix this?

FYI

I don't use CDH distribution just apache Hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have not called any api.

Check http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html

For example:

To list a directory from path /test, you can use the below command,

http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1/test?op=LISTSTATUS

Comment: what do you mean by called api?
i tried this command too http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1/test?op=LISTSTATUS but the result is same. do I have to configure something?

Comment: Can you check once that the property dfs.webhdfs.enabled set in hdfs-site.xml to true.